# Future in akka message

Tags: akka

good day,everyone. 
i have some question about how bad is setting CompletableFuture in mesage from one actor to another and use get() to wait for it compleation. i have code example that i think is too complex to use in practice, but cant find any sutable arguments to advice to refactor it

code that send msg with future

```
private void onSomeSignal(SomeMsg smsg){
   MessageToActor msg = new MessageToActor()
   future = new CompletableFuture<>();
   msg.setFuture(future);
   actortRef.tell(msg, null);
   response = future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   /* do something with responce*/
}
```

code that complete future (in another actor)

```
private void onSomeSignal(MessageToActor msg){
   response = responseService.getResponse();
   msg.getFuture().complete(response);
}
```

is something wrong here , except that future.get() is blocking operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing that will come back and bite you: with this pattern you block one actor until some other actor responds, which means that if you use that elsewhere in your program there is a high risk of running into a deadlock (i.e. your whole program stops and cannot continue).

Instead of using a Future to send back a response, actors are made for sending messages. In “another actor”, you should use `getContext().getSender().tell(response)`, and in the first actor you should handle that response as a normal message instead of the `future.get()` call.

Comment: as far as i can see, main and single goal of this pattern is to bind Response type to request Message. and future.get() may be changed to future.whenComplete() to avoid blocking operation. but this pattern is probably "shared state actor " anti-patern , is not it?

Comment: Yes, that is the core of the issue. If you want to get better type safety, I'd consider using Akka Typed instead, with pure message passing. Futures should never be used for communication between actors.